# whereBetween in certain range

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.5, I want to get the users who were created from a certain range (day, month, year)

### This is my attempt

```
//Range: Year
$users = User::whereBetween('created_at',  ['2019%', '2020%'])->get();

//Range: Month
$users = User::whereBetween('created_at',  ['2019-01%', '2020-05%'])->get();
```

### Expect Output (something like)

```
month  no_users
1        20
2        50  
3        783 
4        983
5        343
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the whole date:

```
//Range: Year
$users = User::whereBetween('created_at',  ['2019-01-01', '2019-12-31'])->get();

//Range: Month
$users = User::whereBetween('created_at',  ['2019-01-01', '2020-05-31'])->get();
```

Comment: this will get me all dates, I want it to be grouped by months, year

Answer (score 0):

```
//In case of Year
$users = User::select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month'))
             ->whereBetween('created_at',  ['2019-01-01', '2019-12-31'])
             ->groupby('year','month')->get();

//In case of Month
$users = User::select(DB::raw('YEAR(created_at) year, MONTH(created_at) month'))
             ->whereBetween('created_at',  ['2019-01-01', '2020-05-31'])
             ->groupby('year','month')->get();
```